# Display results from multiple sources in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Okay, so I'm in the middle of an ASP.NET project in work at the minute and it's all going well. So far I have all the models, views and controllers made and they all work perfectly, but now I have been told that I need to make a class (lets just call it results to make life easy here) to display all the data. This is an example I was given for what the displayed results would look like:

[image: Example of results table]

There are multiple different displays at the moment for different things like a person, travel insurance, car insurance etc. and the only common things between each different display are the full name, contact email, contact number, contact address and recorded time stamp. It's the additional data that changes for each display depending on what is being requested, i.e., person displays all the information stored about the person like full name, age, DOB, mobile number, home address and so on while travel insurance displays all information stored about the travel insurance for the person who is asking like the trip type, trip destination, group type (single/couple/family/friends), travelers ages and so on..

My question is this: **how do I create this results class to display the required data?** Do I need another controller, model and view or do I just need to create a class called Result and put everything into that? (I think I just have to create a class but I am not sure, hence why I am asking) Also, how do I make it in such a way that different things are displayed in the additional data depending on what the person searched for? Like I don't need all the additional data about car insurance appearing when a person searched their travel insurance - does this mean I will need multiple forms of the results class which all refer to a different searchable thing or can everything go in the one class?

Apologies if this is awfully worded and/or a bad question - I did try looking for something to help myself before posting here but I couldn't find anything. I'm also quite new to the whole ASP.NET front so apologies if I'm missing anything obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a base Model class and put all the common properties to be displayed in that, and derive other Model classes from that class with their specific properties in them. You can pass Person object to the view where Person's info need to be displayed and TravelInsurance object where Travel Insurance's info needs to be displayed.

```
    public class ModelBase
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person : ModelBase
    {
        public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public class TravelInsurance : ModelBase
    {
        public string TripType { get; set; }
        public string TripDestination { get; set; }
    }
```

If that does not sound like the way to go, you can have a generic Model class with a generic Data property within it:

```
    public class Model<T>
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
        public T Data { get; set; }
    }

   public class Person
    {
        public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public class TravelInsurance
    {
        public string TripType { get; set; }
        public string TripDestination { get; set; }
    }
```

where you can pass objects to your view like this:

```
    var x = new Model<Person> { FullName = "...", Data = new Person { } };
```

OR

```
    var x = new Model<TravelInsurance> { FullName = "...", Data = new TravelInsurance { } };
```

Comment: Thank you for your very comprehensive answer, I really appreciate it and I will try what you've suggested in work tomorrow.

Comment: You are welcome. Please do not forget to accept as answer if it helps :)

Comment: Yes of course! I'm just going to leave it open for the next day or so but I will accept it then if there are no other answers and/or it is the best one for me :) I find it better to leave things open as some people won't answer questions with accepted answers as they feel there is no point when they could have a very valuable solution, I hope you understand!